# .htaccess force redirect of https://www to https:// not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know there are a ton of the posts concerning this very issue, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

The non-https www or non-www redirects work fine, but I cannont get the https://www redirect to work without getting the untrusted certificate warning.

My .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://arfcc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have cleared the cache and retested to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You know there are a ton of these posts _where_? Hopefully not on stackoverflow, since it's off topic here. Perhaps you mean to post at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Is your certificate for https:// www example.net only, and not for https:// example.net ?

Comment: The very is for the non-www domain only.  Why shouldn't the question belong here?  I have posted several questions concerning code stuff here in the past.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a common catch-22. You need to redirect to the proper hostname to match your SSL cert, BUT, an SSL Handshake has to be established BEFORE any Rewrites can be executed. Most of the webserver's config will not be available until the SSL Handshake and tcp connection is established... including Rewrites.

The most common approach is to use a wildcard and/or SAN certificate to accommodate multiple hostnames.

You can find many articles that cover this, but the following is pretty good:

http://www.jasonsamuel.com/2011/03/07/how-to-properly-use-ssl-redirects-without-getting-certificate-error-messages/

Comment: This is the clearest answer by far.  I thought it might be something along those lines.  I have a SAN certificate, I will just add the other name.  Thanks!